# Cant get nested json with guzzle laravel

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle

Hello guys i have a curl code working well but i cant translate it to guzzle in laravel.

My working code:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$detalle = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
    
$result->detalle_oferta = json_decode($detalle, true);
    
    
echo '<tr>
     <td>'.$result->id.'</td>
     <td>'.$result->comercializadora.'</td>
     <td>'.$result->importePrimerAnio.'</td>
     <td>'.$result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["caracteristicas"].'</td>
     <td>'.$result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["periodoValidez"].'</td>
```

My Laravel Code (No Working)

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
           'base_uri' => 'https://comparador.cnmc.gob.es/api/oferta/?'
            ]);
    
        $result->detalle_oferta = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    
    echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$result->id.'</td>
          <td>'.$result->comercializadora.'</td>
          <td>'.$result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["caracteristicas"].'</td>
          <td>'.$result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["periodoValidez"].'</td>
```

In curl all work fine...
in laravel,  $result->id and $result->comercializadora. work fine... but this $result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["caracteristicas"] and $result->detalle_oferta["caracteristicas"]["periodoValidez"]not work.

the JSON is:

```
 {
    "importeEstimadoPenalizacion":0,
       "id":754,
       "idHistorico":39,
       "idComercializadora":55,
       "idMarca":0,
       "detalle_oferta":{
          "caracteristicas":{
             "caracteristicas":"******I NEED THIS******",
             "periodoValidez":"******AND THIS******"
        }
    }
 }
```

any can help me with this with working example, and explain me what is the difference please?

Comment: Where are you defining `$response`?

Comment: Why are you assigning it to result->detalle_offerta, when the json also has that field?

Comment: where is the request being sent , I guess you are missing this line `$response = $client->request('GET', 'test');`

Comment: Hi! @mrhn is other 1 foreach for oferta and other is result->detalle_oferta